# GPSD Using TCP and Serial

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So I'm attempting to run gpsd on Ubuntu 14.04 with a NMEA feed coming in over TCP and the PPS signal on the DCD line of an RS-232 feed. The GPS I'm using also has the option of using RS-232, but for the case we need it over TCP.

Launching gpsd with the NMEA and PPS over serial works fine. I use something similar to the following:

```
sudo gpsd -n /dev/ttyCTI1 /dev/pps0
```

Then launch gpsmon, and I see both the NMEA strings and the PPS lines come across.

When I start gpsd with the following:

```
sudo gpsd -n tcp://192.168.43.172:10001 /dev/pps0
```

I see only the NMEA strings.

Performing ppstest on /dev/pps0 and ppscheck on /dev/ttyCTI1 produces the expected output.

Any ideas as to what could be wrong? Note that I'm using gpsd 3.18, built from source.

Comment: Guess: gpsd only uses PPS when using a tty (verify by reading gpsd source), possibly because otherwise it can't assume the latencies on both channels are the same. Not sure what format the NMEA TCP packets are; if the format is identical to tty, you could use `socat` to fake a tty for gpsd. However, the latencies will likely be different...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've gone ahead and redirected the TCP stream to /dev/virtualcom0, but am seeing the same results, no pps. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Next idea is "read the source, find out what happens". Or attach `gdb` to a binary with debugging symbols and find out what happens.

Answer (score 0):

dirkt is correct. Answer lies in the gpsd source code. Check out the `ntpshm_link_activate` method in `timehint.c`, line 458:

```
/* don't talk to NTP when we're:
 *   reading from a file
 *   reading from a pipe
 *   reading from a remote gpsd
 *   running inside the test harness (PTY)
 *   over TCP or UDP
 */
if (SOURCE_BLOCKDEV == session->sourcetype ||
    SOURCE_GPSD == session->sourcetype ||
    SOURCE_PIPE == session->sourcetype ||
    SOURCE_PTY == session->sourcetype ||
    SOURCE_TCP == session->sourcetype ||
    SOURCE_UDP == session->sourcetype) {
    return;
}
```

Source: https://fossies.org/dox/gpsd-3.24/timehint_8c_source.html#l00449

This is probably just the beginning of the rabbit hole where `gpsd` decides not to communicate with NTP, but I'll leave it to users better versed than I to scrape through the source code. Regardless, the comment here is very explicit. I can only presume, as Dirkt did, that they do this since the latencies may be much higher in non-serial transmission—which would could lead to misalignments in the NMEA messages being sent over TCP with the connected 1PPS signal. Perhaps you can simply patch this method in the `gpsd` source code to allow NTP communication even on TCP, but I can't guarantee anything good would come of it.

I had the same situation and spent far too long trying to figure it out. Hopefully this helps someone down the road.